# How to find the length of a character array in c which contains multiple characters of asci 0 value

Tags: c, arrays, string-length

I have a character pointer of hex values like as follows.
a= {0x01, 0x02, 0x00, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x00};
I have to find the length of the above array. But strlen gives 2 and sizeof gives 4(char pointer size). How can I find the length? I receive the character array from a socket.

Comment: What marks the end of the array?

Comment: You're probably getting the number of bytes read as a return value from the read-like function.

Comment: If you receive it from a socket you know how many bytes you have received. Just iterate over them and count the 0s.

Comment: @Matthias247: "count the 0s": what for ?

Comment: It depends on the problem. For example, if you know that there are only positive values, you can mark the end of array with -1 or something and then make a function to find the length.

Comment: @zuko32: I  doubt that the OP has control over what he *receives*.

Comment: You can't find the size of the array that the pointer is pointing to. More info in [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array).

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Sorry, I though that was the question and not finding the length. If the length is required - he should already know how much he has received.

Comment: Show real code. `a = {0x01, 0x02, 0x00, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x00};` is incomplete, but the size of the "array" is clearly 7.

Comment: @Matthias247: no worries. Actually, the "length of the array" cannot be revealed by the content, even with a reserved end delimiter (unless known to be the last array element.)

Comment: I know. But he should nevertheless know it. E.g. from the return value of the `read` call to the socket.

Comment: How do you declare the array?

Comment: I don't understand, why do you add the `C++` tag if you are asking about the C language (per your title)?

Answer (score 5):

> How can I find the length?

You can't "find" the length of a buffer using just the pointer. Either you must know the length beforehand, or the buffer must be terminated by some value. As you have described, the buffer is not value-terminated, so you must know the length.

> I receive the character array from a socket.

If you used `ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);` to read from the socket, then you "find" the length of received data from the value that the function returns.

Comment: This sounds like the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

The answer must be, "it depends".

When you have an array and you're not sure how many elements it has, in general there are two ways to handle the situation:

1. Have a second variable holding the count.
2. Use a special "sentinel" value to mark the end.

In C, a string is (by definition) an array of characters, with the special value `'\0'` (the "null character") as a sentinel to mark its end.  So, by definition, it is impossible for a string in C to *contain* a null character.

Since your array is of arbitrary bytes, any of which might be a 0, your array is not a string in the C sense.  So it's likely that the right way to keep track of the length is with a second variable holding the count.  SInce you said that your array was read from a socket, you need to capture the return value of the `read`, `recv`, or `recvfrom` call you used, since that tells you how many character were read.